# How does XGBoost do parallel computation?

Tags: xgboost

XGBoost uses the method of additive training in which it models the residual of the previous model.

This is sequential though, how does it to parallel computing then?

Comment: Thanks for asking--I had the same question.

Comment: A nice blog in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/parallel-computation-with-r-and-xgboost/) to cover parallel and XGboost.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Xgboost doesn't run multiple trees in parallel like you noted, you need predictions after each tree to update gradients.

Rather it does the parallelization WITHIN a single tree my using openMP to create branches independently.

To observe this,build a giant dataset and run with n_rounds=1.  You will see all your cores firing on one tree.  This is why it's so fast- well engineered.

Comment: @T. Scharf But how does this work for multiple nodes i.e. multiple computers rather than 1 computer with multiple cores ? The amount of communication to sync the tree within a tree would be immense

Comment: Yea no getting around this fact.. @AbdealiJK but if your data is so big you need to distribute it this is the price you pay

Comment: @AbdealiJK ^^  yes I agree with your comment.