# What is XGBoost-Spark doing during training and how to optimise its usage of resources?

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I am running XGBoost on Spark 2.2/Scala in cluster mode using spark-submit on Mesos.

I want XGBoost to run in parallel, so I have set the `tree_method=approx` since it is said in [XGBoost Parameters for R](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest//parameter.html) that:

> Distributed and external memory version only support approximate algorithm

It is not clear to me this is also true for Spark version of XGBoost.

I have set XGBoost to use 100 workers (`nWorkers=100`), `total-executor-cores 100` in my `spark-submit` setup and `.config("spark.executor.cores", 5)` in my `SparkSession` setup. In total I have then 20 executors + 1 driver. Each executor with 5 cpus.

In my Stage3 XGBoost starts to run. I see this in the StdOut:

```
Tracker started, with env={DMLC_NUM_SERVER=0, DMLC_TRACKER_URI=192.168.50.105, DMLC_TRACKER_PORT=9091, DMLC_NUM_WORKER=100}
```

In StdErr I see:

```
[Stage 3:>                                                        (0 + 100) / 100]
[Stage 3:>                                                        (0 + 100) / 100]
[Stage 3:>                                                        (0 + 100) / 100]
(repeated many times)
```

In SparkUI-executors tab I see that all 20 executors run 5 tasks each.

In SparkUI-Stage tab, I see 100 tasks running at once.

In Mesos UI - Agents tab I see job running on each node and executor, but never all cpu's running. For each executor, cup utilisation reaches maybe 1.5 at most instead of 5 as requested. It looks like my resources are heavily under-utilised.

XGBoost stays in this state for about 30 minutes producing many `[Stage 3:> ... 0 + 100) / 100] messages` and then at once all tasks are over and the model is ready.

I saw this post [Spark ML gradient boosted trees not using all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181179/spark-ml-gradient-boosted-trees-not-using-all-nodes)
 but it does not help much

I also saw these three articles about parallelisation of XGBoost training phase

1. [How does XGBoost do parallel computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151051/how-does-xgboost-do-parallel-computation)?
2. [Parallel Computation with R and XGBoost](http://www.parallelr.com/parallel-computation-with-r-and-xgboost/)
3. [Parallel Gradient Boosting Decision Trees](http://zhanpengfang.github.io/418home.html)
4. [Parallelism in XGBoost machine learning technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142908/parallelism-in-xgboost-machine-learning-technique?rq=1)

**Questions:**

1. What is XGBoost doing in the Stage3?
2. Is it really parallelised?
3. Why isn't using all 5 cpus at each executor?
4. How to optimize usage of resources during training?
5. From xgboost documentation it is not clear if XGBoost parallelising on columns as in article 3 or on rows with histograms as in 2?
6. Is there a shuffle involved in XGBoost training?