# XGBoost training with n_jobs = -1 not using all cores

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm having problems using all cores on computer for training and cross-validation of XGBoost model.

Data:

```
data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X,label=y, nthread=-1)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train, nthread=-1)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test, nthread=-1)
```

Model:

```
xg_model = XGBRegressor(objective='reg:linear', colsample_bytree= 0.3, learning_rate = 0.2,
                         max_depth = 5, alpha = 10, n_estimators = 100, subsample=0.4, booster = 'gbtree', n_jobs=-1)
```

and than if I do model training with:

```
xgb.train(
    xg_model.get_xgb_params(),
    dtrain,
    num_boost_round=500,
    evals=[(dtest, "Test")],
    early_stopping_rounds=200)
```

It works ok but it uses only 1 thread to run xgboost. 
Processor is on 25%. It ignores  `n_jobs=-1`

But if I do cross-validation with scikit-learn implementation:

```
scores = cross_val_score(xg_model, X, y, cv=kfold, n_jobs=-1)
```

than it uses all cores.
How can I force `xgb.train` and `xgb.cv` to use all cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint mentioned in the best answer selected does not seem to be a critical issue for XGBoost. I have also faced the issue that `n_jobs = -1` is not working. Apparently, it seems to have to do with a known problem in XGBoost. See [here](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/n-jobs-1-no-longer-uses-all-cores/1955/4).

When I set `n_jobs` to the number of threads I require, the usage of multiple cores happened. With `n_jobs = 16`, my training time now is reduced by nearly 10 times.

Comment: it seems like they solved the issue with the 1.3.0 version release.

Answer (score 1):

Boosting is an inherently sequential algorithm, you can only train tree `t+1` after `1..t` has been trained. For parallelization therefore, XGBoost "does the parallelization WITHIN a single tree", as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166401/4553309). With `max_depth=5`, your trees are comparatively very small, so parallelizing the tree building step isn't noticeable.

`cross_val_score` however is training K different XGBoost *models* parallelly. These models are completely independent from each other. From my experience, this sort of coarse grained parallelism using `cross_val_score` or `GridSearchCV` is always faster than parallelizing individual model.

One alternative is to use Random Forest variant: `XGBRFClassifier`. Unlike boosting algorithms, and like `cross_val_score`, random forest is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).

Comment: But I have regression case. Why would then I want to use XGBRFClassifier?

Comment: sry, there is [XGBRFRegressor](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRFRegressor)